# Rename a collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How can I change the name of a collection?

I enter the terminal:

```
use collections
```

I have a "movie" collection and I wanted to convert it to "movies".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `renameCollection()` method.

```
db.movie.renameCollection("movies")
```

Note that there are limitations. This will invalidate any open cursors that are currently returning data and cannot be used to move collections between databases.

Taken from the [mongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.rename()` if you are using mongodb driver, with local mongoDB `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`

the code will be like:

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017')
await client.connect()

await client.db(dbName).collection('movie').rename("movies");

await client.close()
```